# How to save GridView to DataBase in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding, sql-server-ce

in C# I often do it this way:

**Load Table from DataBase to GridView**

```
SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter;
try
   {
      String connectionString = connStr;
      String selectCommand = "select * from Table_Name";

      dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);
      commandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

      DataTable table = new DataTable();
      dataAdapter.Fill(table);
      bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
      DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
   }
catch (SqlCeException ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
```

After do same(much) changes on GridView Cell, I save it to Database this way:

```
dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);
```

Assume I load the table to GridView the same way in WPF. How to save all GridView value to database? (in WPF way :P)

NB: I'm using SQL Server CE for database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date table is a valid data source in wpf, you can do the binding with it(with ItemsSource property), and the saving procedure is not really related to the data grid.

just hold a reference to your table.

Comment: Okay, I success on load table to GridView, but I'm just don't understand how to save. Could you give me a code example?

Comment: The data is automatically bound to the data table, you can save the data table whenever you want, with the data adapter update method.

Comment: I have another question, still the same topic: How to save if I use ObservableCollection<> instead of DataTable? since DataAdapter.Update() can only work on DataTable.

Comment: There are many options... you can start learning ORM like nhibernate or entity framework,or, you can build a mapper, class that will map the Data model to the data table and then save it.

Comment: which one is the easier and better performance? Could you give me acode example, please?